# cannot concatenate 'str' and 'ImageFieldFile' objects Django

Tags: django

cannot concatenate 'str' and 'ImageFieldFile' objects

```
filename = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + self.image
```

Running Python 2.5 (Django 1.3) on a Debian Linux server.

Comment: Come on, this isn't even a question! Provide code, what you're trying to do, what you've tried to do etc.

Comment: @vicvicvic don't you see the code?

Comment: It was added after my comment.

Answer (score 6):

Use `image.name`:

```
filename = self.image.name
```

> If you wanted to retrieve the uploaded
>   file's on-disk filename, or the file's
>   size, you could use the name and size
>   attributes respectively; for more
>   information on the available
>   attributes and methods, see the File
>   class reference and the Managing files
>   topic guide.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField

Answer (score -1):

`self.image` is an object, not a string: decide which attribute you want to concatenate with `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` and then use that attribute:

e.g.

```
file_path = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + self.image.name
```

However, I agree that a question should be formed in a better way...

Comment: Won't image.name contain an absolute path? Why `settings.MEDIA_ROOT +` ?

Comment: @Silver Light No, absolute path is in `image.path`

Comment: @DrTyrsa I think you are wrong. See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File

Comment: @Silver Light Have you clicked your link? "The name of file including the relative path from MEDIA_ROOT".

Comment: ...and MEDIA_ROOT is an absolute path to media root.

Comment: @Silver Light Yes, but `MEDIA_ROOT` isn't included in `image.name`. Here's `image.name` for an image in my current project: `logos/b764baf5547c745f2f69ed04083998c5.gif`. Does it look like an absolute path?

Comment: Ok, but the question is not about how to get absolute path of an image but why it is not possible to concatenate a string to an ImageField instance